# Magento Admin panel will not fully load Edit Categories due to AJAX call to a non secure endpoint

Tags: admin, magento-1, url, https, secure

We have a Magento site that was copied over from an existing Magento site we have, so all products, setting, etc are simply copied to a new domain.

This was done months ago but I am just now trying to use the site.  Frontend of site seems to be working great.

Admin panel, in the edit categories page, it keeps "Loading"

I look at the Browser COnsole on this page instantly see this problem....

```
Mixed Content: The page at  
'https://www.domain.com/index.php/admin/catalog_category/index/key/7ac5ce7838cd82114132424faf2b5656/'  
was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint  
'http://www.domain.com/index.php/admin/catalog_category/edit/key/40eeadefd754406a47f2993be70c4472/?isAjax=true'.  
This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

So it appears this page is making an AJAX call to `http://www.domain.com/index.php/admin/catalog_category/edit/key/40eeadefd754406a47f2993be70c4472/?isAjax=true` notice the `http` instead of `https`

I think fixing this will fix our issues.

In admin config I saw this setting: `Use Secure URLs in Admin` was set to `No` so I changed it to `yes` but no luck on the error going away just yet.

Any ideas how to resolve this please?

**UPDATE**

It seems my Admin setting for ``Use Secure URLs in Admin`is not saving!  So changing it;s value to`yes`is not saving and end up staying as`no` so it seems we have more issues.  The solution to the admin setting saving could fix the other issue.

Any ideas here?

Answer (score 4):

I got it fixed now, i'll explain the process below...

My admin panel was loading through `HTTPS` URL's due to our server configuration.  However in the Magento Admin panel this option

`Config > General > Web` `Use Secure URLs in Admin` was set to `NO`

[image]

---

I knew changing this to `Yes` would probably fix all our admin panel issues.  However changing it to yes and hitting `Save Config` would submit and show a message indicating it had save the config.  However the value for that option above still showed up as `No`!

So in Chrome Developer Tools, I viewed the source of the webpage and found the `<form>` that was on the options page.

[image]

---

After changing the Form URL to `https` in the DOM, I then changed the option to a `yes` value again and hit `Save Config`.  This time since it made my `POST` to the correct `https` URL, it actually made the save and updated the value!

With that updated, all my admin problems are resolved!

Comment: awesome. You save my life. Thanks so much