# Category in admin side not loading

Tags: category, admin-panel, magento2.3, magento2.3.0

After clicking in any category the page is not loading .Please find the below screenshot of the page.

[image]

[image]

Any body know why it is like this?

Comment: I hope this link will help you.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/60403/magento-admin-panel-will-not-fully-load-edit-categories-due-to-ajax-call-to-a-no

Comment: this is not working.

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: nop i have reinstalled the magento